# Call href from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey, href

This is the same question as [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782556/calling-href-from-javascript), I can't answer that anymore, so I'm re-posting it with my account.
Sorry for the mess.

I need a Greasemonkey script that on a page load activates a href link like 'javascript:FUNCTION'.
I've seen this code:

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function somescript() {
            window.location.href = document.getElementById('ololo').href;
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:alert('test');" id="ololo">test</a>
<br />

<a href="javascript:somescript()">click me</a>
```

and, while it works on a local page even when using onload, it doesn't work when I use it in my script.

Probably I'm missing something when transferring the code from the body of an html page to a Greasemonkey script.

I hope this time the question is more clear, excuse me for any misunderstanding, but I'm still a beginner with JS.

Comment: The script it's still WIP, but the function I need it's the first one that should work, otherwise nothing else will.  
To keep it more clear: the rest of the script doesn't conflict with this function.

Comment: No errors, simply it doesn't work. That's why I don't even know what's wrong with it.
Correct me please, to export that function to a Greasemonkey one, should I just ditch the <script> tags?

Comment: If you need serious greasemonkey help, ask on userscripts.org

Comment: You shouldn't have any html tags in a js script. If you do it should give you an error. (Tools > Error Console). PLEASE POST YOUR SCRIPT. I cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
window.location=document.getElementById('foo').href;
```

Thanks everyone for answering anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function somescript() {
        eval(document.getElementById('ololo').getAttribute('href').replace('javascript:', ''));
    }
</script>
```

I can see the alert box..

Please note that this will only work when its javascript code into the href attribute...

Comment: If you want to fake a click on the link instead, there's an example here... it seems like a lot of work without a 3rd party library: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/browse_thread/thread/27e7c70e51ff8a99/98cea9cdf065a524%2398cea9cdf065a524?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for your scenario?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function somescript() {
    document.getElementById('ololo').click();//fake a click on the link
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
Is it possible that a website forbids this kind of actions?

Comment: The jQuery library provides a cross browser function to "click" a link/button, so it can work. How they do it, should be seen in their source code though...

Comment: This might work if a jQuery click Event is bound to this element.