# Can't trigger click event on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

My problem is that I got 2 aspx controls generated like this :

```
<a id="sortByDate" href="javascript:__doPostBack('sortByDate','')">Date</a>
<a id="sortByLastName" href="javascript:__doPostBack('sortByLastName','')">Last name</a>
```

so those links allow you to sort the results. I'm trying to put this in a combobox instead of using links.

So I made it like this

```
<select id="sortBySelect" onchange="javascript:sortBy(this);">
       <option value="sortByLastName">Last name</option>
       <option value="sortByDate">Date</option>
</select>
```

with this javascript function

```
function sortBy(sel) {
    var id = sel.value;
    $("#" + id).trigger("click");
}
```

So when you change the selected element in the combobox I want to trigger the click event on the link to call the dopostback to sort.

It does nothing so far. I tried "click", "onclick", "onClick" and nothing works. Unfortunately, this is for IE quirks mode.

I know, this is really not elegant, but I'm really short in time and I need something quick and dirty. I will make an aspx control eventually to handle this nicely.

Any ideas how I could make this work in ie quirks mode?

Thank you

Comment: `console.log(id)` - is it getting the value? Where's the click handler for those anchors?

Comment: Yes, I had an alert. I got the good id

Comment: Any chance of a jsfiddle?

Comment: `.trigger()` is for firing events created with `.on()` afaik.

Comment: @ChrisG. good point.. At first I used this http://www.guahanweb.com/2010/03/02/how-to-manually-trigger-events-in-javascript/  maybe I should go back to it

Comment: @ChrisG. it works with `.on()` or one of its shortcut methods (such as `.click()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the location of the page:

```
document.location = $("#" + id).attr('href');
```

Comment: will this actually trigger a postback, I'm not sure?

Comment: This will have the same effect that clicking the link, so yes

Comment: it's not a click it's a url change, nothing to see with op needs

Comment: @r043v I didn't say that it was a click, I said that has the same effect: a url change

Comment: op need launch __doPostBack method, not sure this code will launch it

Comment: @r043v I have tested with other javascript code and it works, `__doPostBack` is a javascript function

Comment: Won't be long, I'm gonna try all those solutions soon. The client's server is unavailable as USUAL...

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just fire the `__doPostBack` directly:

```
function sortBy(sel) {
    var id = sel.value;
    __doPostBack(id,'');   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

<strike>function sortBy(sel) {
<strike>var id = sel.value;</strike>
<strike>alert($("#" + id).length);//just for conforming that the element exists.</strike>
<strike>$("#" + id).click();</strike>}</strike>

Actually, jQuery only triggers any **event** bound to an element. You are trying to call the href action.

If you don't want to change the markup, you could try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1786360/405398).

Otherwise, you will have to change your html markup to bind javascript events & then try triggering it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Everything works as intended!

## [JSFiddle proof.](http://jsfiddle.net/3pmGf/)

Make sure you have an element with the id `sortById` and `sortByLastName` !

---

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sortByDate').click(function(){
        alert('Sort By Date Click Event fired!');
    })
});
function sortBy(sel) {
    var id = sel.value;
    $("#" + id).trigger("click");
}
```

---

### [Alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/3pmGf/1/)

Force the `window.location` change

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
function sortBy(sel) {
    var id = sel.value;
   window.location =  $("#" + id).attr('href');
}
```

Note: You won't see any change in JSFiddle:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.ca/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```